# htaccess redirect (multidomain multilanguage) subfolder wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, internationalization

I have a typo3 installation with multidomain and multilanguage, where not every language is setup to every domain.

Languages are **`de/fr/en/pt/es/cn/`**

`www.example.de` can be `de/en/fr` but not
`www.example.de pt/es/cn`

now I have messed up sth. and google has indexed loads of wrong urls e.g.

```
www.example.de/pt/
www.example.de/es/
www.example.de/cn/
```

they point to languages that are not set for this domain

I am fiddling around in the htaccess to redirect 301 the wrong urls with wildcards(?) to the .tld

I am looking for a solution redirect eg.

```
www.example.de/pt/* to www.example.de/
www.example.de/es/* to www.example.de/
www.example.de/cn/* to www.example.de/
```

where the * should represent the complete sting/path following the language parameter.

and of cause the same procedure for the .com domain

```
www.example.com/fr/* to www.example.com/
www.example.com/de/* to www.example.com/
```

I searched the web up and down but nothing I tried works.
any help would highly apreciated.

---

a tiny step further

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de
RewriteRule ^cn/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pt/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]
```

this seems to work

and now for the second domain as I need to differentiate between .com and .de

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

this now breaks `www.example.de/fr/whatever` and redirects it to `www.example.com` as well.

so it looks like the first condition is matching and the the last rule is applied for french.

how can I limit the rules assigning them only to the appropriate domain conditions?

Answer (score 0):

ok looks like every condition and respective rule needs to be written in a single line an repeated

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de
RewriteRule ^cn/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de
RewriteRule ^pt/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ http://www.example.de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

this seems to work.

any better solution is highly appreciated