# One website / three languages / three domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I've got one website with three languages and three domains:
cheese.org, fromage.org and kaese.org

I want to create the following redirects (whith wildcards *)

```
cheese.org/fr/* redirects to fromage.org
cheese.org/de/* redirects to kaese.org
fromage.org/en/* redirects to cheese.org
fromage.org/de/* redirects to kaese.org
kaese.org/en/* redirects to cheese.org
kaese.org/fr/* redirects to fromage.org
```

I fiddled around with [htaccess redirect (multidomain multilanguage) subfolder wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627788/htaccess-redirect-multidomain-multilanguage-subfolder-wildcard) but didn't get it right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward... Depending on the http host you need to redirect incoming requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cheese\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kaese\.org$
RewriteCond ^/?fr/(.*) https://fromage.org/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fromage\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kaese\.org$
RewriteCond ^/?en/(.*) https://cheese.org/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cheese\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fromage\.org$
RewriteCond ^/?de/(.*) https://kaese.org/$1 [R=301]
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).